# openload.cc How can I extract encoding settings of videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, encoding, transcode

My customer needs streaming service for his IP cameras and he ask me about same output quality as videos in openload.cc but I can´t simulate similar quality.I tried several encoding combination but nothing works fine.

Original video from cameras is good quality but Xvid codec is used. 
So I use ffmpeg for live transcoding to AVC because Xvid can´t be streamed.

My client needs reduce quality/size with good visibility in output I ask my client about choice which online service has good visibility for him and he choose openload.cc

clarification: AVC can use less bitrate with good visibility - for example:

Original IP camera video (Xvid) 
40 minutes -> about 350MB

Openload video 480p (AVC) 40 minutes -> about 180MB

Needed output sample is [here](http://openloadmovies.net/episodes/marvels-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-1x4/?player=option-1) 480p (sorry about warez but I can´t find no warez content on openload

So I need find openload encoding settings now. I try to save file and then use mediainfo but mediainfo did not detect full encoding settings (like CRF, one or two encoding pass, specific video bitrate - mediainfo detect only range of bitrate...)

I use ffmpeg as encoder so now I need to know which settings I need to use for same output quality as in [480p](http://openloadmovies.net/episodes/marvels-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-1x4/?player=option-1) sample.

Thank you for help me.